# Google Scripts - Modify Table Cell in Table with different number of columns in each row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I am trying to modify a google document table that has multiple rows, but each row has different number of columns.

Here is an example table
[image]

How do I use table.getCell(row,col) or row.getCell(col) to get the contents of a,b,c,d,e,f,g etc..

What is the proper way to address each cell and modify the contents. The tables I am dealing with have a defined structure.

```
  tables.forEach(function(table) {
    var numberOfRows = table.getNumRows();
    console.log("New Table with Rows: " + numberOfRows);
    for (var rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < numberOfRows; rowIndex++) {
      var row = table.getRow(rowIndex);
      // this is a table of interest and we know the exact structure
      if(rowIndex == 0 && row.getCell(0).getText().toString().trim().includes("2 cols")){
        row.getCell(0).editAsText().setText("11");
        row.getCell(1).editAsText().setText("12");
      }else if(rowIndex == 1 && row.getCell(0).getText().toString().trim().includes("3 cols")){
        row.getCell(1).editAsText().setText("21");
        row.getCell(2).editAsText().setText("22");
      }else if(rowIndex == 2 && row.getCell(0).getText().toString().trim().includes("5 cols")){
          row.getCell(1).editAsText().setText("31");
          row.getCell(2).editAsText().setText("32");  // NOTE1: THIS IS THE ISSUE
          row.getCell(3).editAsText().setText("33");  // NOTE3: THIS IS THE ISSUE
      }
    }
  })
```

Here is the table output of the code above
[image]

How come NOTE1 and NOTE2 did not modify cells e, and cells f?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought that in your script, the values of `getColSpan()` of `row.getCell(1)`, `row.getCell(2)` and `row.getCell(3)` are `3`, `0` and `0`, respectively. When the value of `getColSpan()` is `0`, it means the merged cell. I thought that this might be the reason for your issue. So, in order to achieve your goal, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
row.getCell(1).editAsText().setText("31");
row.getCell(2).editAsText().setText("32");  // NOTE1: THIS IS THE ISSUE
row.getCell(3).editAsText().setText("33");  // NOTE3: THIS IS THE ISSUE
```

#### To:

```
var nCol = 0;
var values = ["31", "32", "33"];
for (var colIndex = 1; colIndex < row.getNumCells(); colIndex++) {
  var cell = row.getCell(colIndex);
  if (values.length > nCol && cell.getColSpan() > 0) {
    cell.editAsText().setText(values[nCol++]);
  }
}
```

- By this modification, the row of `5 cols` has the values of `5 cols, 31, 32, 33`.

Comment: Resolved! Thank you. Not sure why I am struggling with these tables. You are helping out very much.

Comment: @Sliffcak Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.